# Problem with while loop in game (python text game)

Tags: python, while-loop

I have been working on a game and what I have is what I have placed down below. The problem with it is that Whenever you run away from the enemy whether you are successful or not you DO run away and I dont know how to stop this from happening. Does anyone have any suggestions?

edit: in order to solve the problem I deleted the
if slime_rank1_chances > 0:
because it's supposed to be 100% at the start of the game and I changed the
while slime_rank1_health != 0:
into
while slime_rank1_health > 0:

```
import random

#rng
dice = random.randrange(1,7)
critical_hit_chance = 15
run_chance = 10

#characters
name_1_health = 10
name_1_attack = 10
name_1_luck = 10
name_1_exp = 0

#enemies
slime_rank1_health = 10
slime_rank1_attack = 1
slime_rank1_luck = 1
slime_rank1_exp = 5
slime_rank1_chances = random.randrange(1,10)

#simulating an attack by a slime rank 1
if slime_rank1_chances > 0:
    print("you are suddenly attacked by a slime rank 1!")
    while slime_rank1_health != 0:
        if random.randrange(1, 16) == critical_hit_chance:
            name_1_health = name_1_health - (slime_rank1_attack*2)
            print("Its a critical hit!")
            print("you have lost " + str(slime_rank1_attack*2) + " health")
        else:
            name_1_health = name_1_health - slime_rank1_attack
            print("you have lost " + str(slime_rank1_attack) + " health")
        print("your current health is " + str(name_1_health))
        slime_rank1_choice1 = input("What will you do?: A)Attack B)Run [A/B]")
        while True:
            if slime_rank1_choice1 in ["A","B"]:
                break
        if slime_rank1_choice1 == "A":
            print("You attack slime rank 1")
            if random.randrange(1, 16) == critical_hit_chance:
                slime_rank1_health = slime_rank1_health - (name_1_attack*2)
                print("You attack and deal "+str(name_1_attack*2)+" damage")
                print("Its a critical hit!")
            else: 
                slime_rank1_health = slime_rank1_health - name_1_attack
                print("You attack and deal "+str(name_1_attack)+" damage") 
        elif slime_rank1_choice1 == "B":
            print("you have chosen to run")
            if random.randrange(1,11) == run_chance:
                print("you have succesfully escaped!")
                slime_rank1_health = slime_rank1_health - slime_rank1_health
            else: 
                print("you failed to escape")
                if random.randrange(1, 16) == critical_hit_chance:
                    name_1_health = name_1_health - (slime_rank1_attack*2)
                    print("Its a critical hit!")
                    print("you have lost " + str(slime_rank1_attack*2) + " health")
                else:
                    name_1_health = name_1_health - slime_rank1_attack
                    print("you have lost " + str(slime_rank1_attack) + " health")
        break
```

Comment: So the print statement "you have successfully escaped!" prints every time you choose "B", and you expect that to only happen 10% of the time?  Just making sure I understand the bug

Comment: And I know you're a new coder--my early code looks the same!--but your life will become a _lot_ easier if you break apart these giant code blocks into smaller functions.  Like, maybe make a function called damage_slime(damage_amount), for example, that decrements the slime's health by X amount.  Just a suggestion

Comment: yes, that is the bug but I just managed to fix it. Im about to edit the post if you want to see what I changed. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Don't edit your post!  Just post an answer!  Editing won't help future people

Comment: Just saw you other comment and that does look alot easier, thx

Comment: I edited the edit to show the original code and the answer at the same time so no worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that the code ends every time you try to run, whether or not you were successful.  Your if/else statement looks OK, but either way it hits the break at the end.

Consider making a function to manage your game play and smaller functions to manage mechanics like running, attacking, changing hit points, etc.  That might help you organize your code better and make things clearer.  Keep at it--it's looking good!